# Understanding the demonstration of bus waiting paradox

Tags: probability

My teacher gave me a demonstration of the idea behind the bus waiting paradox, but I'm having some issues understanding one of the initial assumptions.

Convention here is that *X* is the time between two arrivals, while *Y* is the waiting time.

The demonstration starts by saying that

$$
E[Y]=\int_{0}^\infty E[Y|A_t]*P(A_t)\label{a}\tag{1}
$$

where $A_t$ is the event defined as

$$
A_t= \text{"arrival happening during a realization } x \text{ of } X : t \le x \le t+dt"
$$

He also adds that

$$
E[Y|A_t]=\int_{u=0}^t u*f_{Y|A_t}(u)*du=\frac1t*\int_{u=0}^t u*du = \frac t2\label{b}\tag{2}
$$

What I don't understand is how both $(1)$ and $(2)$ work, from a formal point of view, even if I have a rough idea.

So, what I'd like to know is if someone can provide all the steps to prove the two equalities.

EDIT - adding the full demonstration just for clarity

*Thesis:*

$$
E[Y]=\frac{E[X^2]}{2*E[X]}=\frac12*E[x]+\frac{VAR(X)}{2*E[X]}
$$

*Demonstration:*

$$
P(A_t)=c*t*f_X(t)*dt; c=\frac{1}{E[X]}
$$

$$
E[Y]=\int_{0}^\infty E[Y|A_t]*P(A_t)
$$

$$
E[Y|A_t]=\frac t2
$$

$$
E[Y]=\int_{0}^\infty E[Y|A_t]*P(A_t)=\int_{0}^\infty \frac t2 * \frac{t*f_X(t)}{E[X]}*dt=\frac{E[X^2]}{2E[X]}
$$

Comment: You will have to describe what you mean by the "bus waiting paradox" before we can answer this.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222674/average-bus-waiting-time

Comment: @TonyK I'va also added the full demonstration, maybe it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) is just the Law of Total Probability in disguise, and (assuming $X$ has a density function $f_X$) can be less obtusely written as
$$
E[Y]=\int_0^\infty E[Y\mid X=t]\,f_X(t)\,dt.
$$
But $X$ is the sum of two iid random variables, $Y$ and $Z$ (say). By symmetry
$$
E[Y\mid X=t]=E[Z\mid X=t],
$$
but also 
$$
E[Y\mid X=t]+E[Z\mid X=t]=E[Y+Z\mid X=t]=E[X\mid X=t]=t.
$$
It follows that $E[Y\mid X=t]=t/2$. This is (2).